# How to generate composition of two tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

How can I generate a table {(y,z)} that is a composition of two other separate tables {(x,y)} and {(y,z)}.

I have two 2-column tables, RelOne and RelTwo. The rows in each table represent ordered pairs of a many-to-many relationship.

**RelOne** is

```
(a, 1)  
(b, 1)  
(c, 1)  
(a, 2)   
(b, 2)
```

**RelTwo** is

```
(1, East)  
(1, West)  
(2, East)   
(2, South)  
(2, West)  
(2, North)
```

There are no natural keys for either table.

I want to generate a third table that is composition of RelOne and RelTwo that would be

```
(a, East)  
(b, East)  
(c, East)  
(a, West)  
(b, West)  
(c, West)  
(a, East)  
(a, South)   
(a, West)   
(a, North)  
(b, East)   
(b, South)   
(b, West)   
(b, North)
```

These values are a simplification; the actual tables have hundreds of rows.

Answer (score 1):

On first glance, this seemed silly simple, but... it isn't.

I think a possible solution is a reduced cross-product - if you look at the counts, RelOne has 3 '1' and 2 '2', and RelTwo has 2 '1' and 4 '2'; the result has 3*2 '1' + 2*4 '2' = 13 entries. There is no simple way to produce this total count except of counting all 1, 2, 3, etc in both your tables, obviously tedious.
Therefore (and I'll skip any Macro/VBA/3rdParty solutions), i recommend the following approach:

1. Consider a cross-product between the tables - combine each entry from RelOne with each entry of RelTwo. that will give you N * M lines (here: 5*6 = 30).
2. Put a formula into each of those cross products that verifies if the keys match
3. You will get a long table with N * M lines, and a second column that contains TRUE or FALSE depending on if the keys match
4. Sort and discard all FALSE.

For the practical execution, put formulas in N * M lines, and use `ROW()%N` and `INT(ROW()/N)` to generate the indexes into the two tables - those two will iterate through all N * M combinations. The rest should be straightforward if you understand what I describe, and you know your way with formulas.